# Second Laravel installation redirecting to the previous Laravel installation and blank page issue

Tags: laravel-4

Steps that created the issue:

1. Previous Laravel 4 installation exists (Status: Working Perfect!)
2. Installed second Laravel 4 project. After installation, I opened the project in browser, it redirects me to the previously installed Laravel index page.
3. Tried installing Laravel 4 the third time. Same issue. Both, the installation points to the first Laravel index page.

Tried (Steps didn't solve the problem):

1. chmod 755 permission to app/storage
2. restarted apache2 several times

Next Step I took something strange happened:

1. I removed the first Laravel 4 project from the server.
2. Now, when I open the second and third Laravel projects. Both, the installation gives me a white blank page/screen. No error, nothing.
3. I set debug to true, still nothing.
4. Then, I tried to load the page without public in the url. Instead of getting a list of folders (app, bootstrap, public and vendor) and files. I still get a blank screen.
5. I copied back the first working Laravel project to the server. Same problem starts, the second and third installation points to the first Laravel index page.

I am using Lubuntu 14.04 32 bit. I tried several other things, searched for solutions in google and stackoverflow for hours. Still, couldn't solve the problem. Just don't know what I am missing here. Help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No Reply yet? Anyone? I don't expect perfect answers. Any hint, anything... so that I can proceed debugging this problem. I am stuck.

Comment: Hey Michael, please explain what you do to launch the server. Do you use "php artisan serve" on your laravel installation. Or do you setup a vhost? 

In any case, probably you are running the server of your first installation and haven't quitted it yet. Take a careful look into your terminal windows, I believe you have more than one open.

Comment: Hi @LoveAndHappiness, thanks for replying. I am using vhosts for launching the server. When I launch the server using "php artisan serve", it works fine. But, with vhosts it doesn't work at all.

I have a windows system too. Installed both the projects in xampp. Works perfectly fine in windows using vhosts.

Checked vhosts(in linux) several times. I didn't find anything missing. I have other projects besides Laravel project. Using vhosts for all and they are working fine.

Comment: @LoveAndHappiness Going to uninstall and reinstall Apache2. Will let you know of how it goes..

Comment: @LoveAndHappiness I re-installed Apache2. Still the same issue. But, I think you are right. Previous project session is still running. So when I run the second one, it doesn't open. Instead, page from the previous session opens. I've got a workaround the issue. I could use "php artisan serve" or I will have to clear cache every time I run Laravel(for vhosts).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're missing a configuration for your new site in your /etc/hosts file, or a missing Virtual Host. When you hit the URL for your 2nd installation, the browser doesn't know where to go.

Comment: There's a good, clear walkthrough of how to set up both the virtual host and local host (/etc/hosts) at [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) for Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am using vhosts for Laravel and other projects. Only Laravel doesn't work with vhosts. When, I use "php artisan serve" then it works fine. I checked vhost and host file several times. If there was something missing in vhost or host file, then other projects also shouldn't have worked. Going to uninstall and reinstall Apache2. Will let you know of how it goes..

Comment: I re-installed Apache2. Still the same issue. I am in a tight schedule. Have to make something work so I've got a workaround the issue. I could use "php artisan serve" or I will have to clear cache every time I run Laravel(for vhosts).

Comment: Could you post the vhost config file for each site (`/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf`), and your local hosts file (`/etc/hosts`)? Otherwise we're troubleshooting in the dark. Also, did you enable the second site with `sudo a2ensite example.com.conf` before restarting apache?